# What is the correct way to programmatically delete a joomla user and their data?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to remove a set of users by id from a Joomla 3.x database. I am trying to figure out from the documentation if this is possible without having to write my own SQL for each database table.

**Something like the following pseudo code:**

```
 delete from #_users where ( `lastvisitDate` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH  ) AND ( #__user_usergroup_map.group_id = 18 );
 delete from #_user_usergroup_map where user_id not in (select id from #_users);
 delete from #_user_profiles where user_id not in (select id from #_users);
```

I am familiar with the querybuilder see: https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase/en

But if there is already code in the framework that deletes user's with details then it would be my preference not to reinvent the wheel.

The documentations has this : https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.User.User.html but it seems that no parameters are passed to user->delete?

I'm assuming this can be done as it is possible to tick boxes in the administrator back end user list and delete multiple users.

I have been working with Joomla for a few years (since 1.5) but truth be told I have always struggled with the API documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question Ryan. It might get more attention at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The function is in the model for com_users

```
/administrator/components/com_users/models/user.php
```

You can load this model from a controller like this:

```
$model = parent::getModel($name = 'User', $prefix = 'UsersModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true));
```

then

```
$model->delete($pks);
```

where `$pks` is an array of user ids to delete.